# Restrict generic parameter to protocols inheriting from protocol

Tags: swift, generics, inheritance, protocols

I'm not sure what `where` clause can restrict a generic parameter to be a protocol that inherits from a certain protocol.

```
protocol Edible {}
protocol PetFood: Edible {}
struct CatFood: PetFood {}
struct Rocks {}

func eat<T: Edible>(_ item: T) -> String {
    return "Just ate some \(type(of: item))"
}

let food: CatFood = CatFood()
eat(food) //"Just ate some CatFood"

let moreFood: PetFood = CatFood()
//eat(moreFood) //Cannot invoke 'eat' with an argument list of type '(PetFood)'

func eatAnything<T>(_ item: T) -> String {
    return "Just ate some \(type(of: item))"
}

eatAnything(moreFood) //This works, obviously
eatAnything(Rocks()) //But, of course, so does this...
```

Is there any way to restrict `eatAnything()` to allow protocol types, but only those that inherit from `Edible`?

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the definition of a generic function does not make any sense because it can be replaced by:

```
func eat(_ item: Edible) -> String {
    return "Just ate some \(type(of: item))"
}
```

But if you really want to use generic function then you should know:

1. Definition of generic function

   - `func eat<T: Edible>(_ item: T) -> String { ... }`
   - `func eat<T>(_ item: T) -> String where T: Edible { ... }`
   - `func eat<T: Edible>(_ item: T) -> String where T: Equatable { ... }`
2. Protocols are dynamic types, so they use late binding. Generic code is converted to normal during compilation and requires early binding

   - **Early Binding** *(compile time)*: type is known before the variable is exercised during run-time, usually through a static, declarative means
   - **Late Binding** *(runtime)*: type is unknown until the variable is exercised during run-time; usually through assignment but there are other means to coerce a type; dynamically typed languages call this an underlying feature
3. Generic functions can be defined with the type to be protocol-compatible, but this functions can't pass the this protocol as type, because the compiler doesn't know what that type is `T`. Passed to generic function type must be a specific type (class, struct, enum, ...)

---

```
let a: [Int] = [1,2,3]
let b: [CustomStringConvertible] = [1, "XYZ"]

a.index(of: 2) // 1
b.index(of: "XYZ") // error
```

Comment: Well, sure--it's just a simple example to demonstrate the question.